# Check nodeType for Pictures/Alt Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I got a recursive function which goes through all HTML Child Nodes.

Is there an easy way to check if the current element is an image with element.nodeType? So I could use DOM onto this element.

Here an example of the code:

`

```
replaceText(document.body)

function replaceText(element){
    if(element.hasChildNodes()){
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)
    } else if(element.nodeType === Text.TEXT_NODE){
//Do Something
}
```

`

Just like that but also for pictures and especially for the pictures alt attribute.

Comment: Thanks, and then how can i get onto the alt attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `nodeName` property of the element to check if it's an image ("IMG") once you are sure it's not a text node.

```js
replaceText(document.body)

function replaceText(element){
    if(element.hasChildNodes()){
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)
    } else if(element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE){
      console.log("Text Found! textContent: ",element.textContent)
    }
    else if(element.nodeName === "IMG"){
      console.log("Image Found! Alt: ",element.alt)
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>this is text</p>
<div>this is an element</div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/22" alt="i am an image">
</body>
</html>
```

To get the `alt` property of an image, just use `element.alt` in your code.

---

TO remove the image if text in it matches a regex, just test each property you want tested:

```js
function replaceText(element){
    if(element.hasChildNodes()){
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)
    } else if(element.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE){
      //console.log("Text Found! textContent: ",element.textContent)
    }
    else if(element.nodeName === "IMG"){
      console.log("Image Found! Alt: ",element.alt)
      let re = /Wendler/gi
      if((element.alt != undefined &&element.alt.match(re)) || (element.src != undefined &&element.src.match(re)) || (element.title != undefined &&element.title.match(re))){ 
        element.remove()
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>this is text</p>
<div>this is an element</div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/22" alt="i am an image">
<img src="https://placehold.it/25" alt="i am an image containing the word wendLer somewhere">
<img src="https://placehold.it/25?text=wendler" alt="i am an image">


<button onclick="replaceText(document.body)">Click to remove images</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah i got that, right now i just want to remove the image if the src/title/alt attribute contains the word "Wendler".  I tried out                                       
   else if(element.nodeType = "IMG"){
        if(element.src.match(/Wendler/gi)){
            element.parentElement.remove()
        }   but didnt work yet :(

Comment: `element.parentElement.remove()` won't just remove  the image, but also the surrounding (parent) element

Comment: I think i understand, my goal is just to remove the image even if i have to delete the sorrounding parent object. Of course on removing the img would be better but element.remove()  doesnt work either.

Comment: See my edit. I works fine there, maybe check your code for errors again :-)

Comment: Hmm, as you probably will have recognized i want to implement the code as a chrome extension. However when im implementing the extension,  it shows me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" which should mean the element is undefind, but that doenst makes a lot of sense in my opinion ?

Comment: Can you post your current code as an edit to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208337/discussion-between-robert-betschinger-and-luca-kiebel).